# Instantiating InMemorySigner

Tags: tezos-signer

While instantiating InMemorySigner, we should provide the "Encoded private key". Is there a way of generating this Encoded private key from the .json file I get from the faucet?

```
Tezos.setProvider({
  signer: new InMemorySigner('YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY'),
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `signer = InMemorySigner.fromFundraiser(email, password, mnemonic);` or `importKey(Tezos, email, password, mnemonic.join(' '), secret);` from `@taquito/taquito-signer`

[An example](https://tezostaquito.io/docs/inmemory_signer#using-a-testnet-faucet-key)